# after ListView_SortItemsEx, ListView_FindItem always returns -1

Tags: c++, winapi

After ListView_SortItemsEx, ListView_FindItem always returns -1, that is, it finds nothing. Can you tell me why this behavior?

I tried to search by lParam and by psz, the result is the same, just after the standard alphabetical sorting, without specifying the callback function, the result is the same, I am not English-speaking, I write through a translator, if something is wrong, I apologize

A minimally reproducible example

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "commctrl.h"
#include "vector"
#include "string"
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

HINSTANCE hinst;
HWND hwndMain;
HWND hwndList;

LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int CreateColumn(HWND hwndLV, int iCol, CHAR* Text, int iWidth)
{
    LVCOLUMN lvc;

    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    lvc.cx = iWidth;
    lvc.pszText = Text;
    lvc.iSubItem = iCol;
    return ListView_InsertColumn(hwndLV, iCol, &lvc);
}

int CreateItem(HWND hwndList, CHAR* text, int index)
{
    LVITEM lvi = { 0 };
    int res;

    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_IMAGE;
    lvi.iItem = index;
    lvi.pszText = text;
    lvi.lParam = 0;
    res = ListView_InsertItem(hwndList, &lvi);

    if (res >= 0)
    {
        ListView_SetItemText(hwndList, res, 0, text);
    }

    return res;
}

void fillListView()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        CreateItem(hwndList, (CHAR*)std::to_string(i).c_str(), i);
    }
}

// функция обратново вызова для сортировки
int CALLBACK CompareListViewFunc(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM lParamSort)
{
    std::vector<CHAR> str1(MAX_PATH);
    std::vector<CHAR> str2(MAX_PATH);

    ListView_GetItemText(hwndList, lParam1, 0, &str1.front(), MAX_PATH);
    ListView_GetItemText(hwndList, lParam2, 0, &str2.front(), MAX_PATH);

    if (strcmp(&str1.front(), &str2.front()) == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (strcmp(&str1.front(), &str2.front()) == 1)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return -1;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpszCmdLine);

    // Register the window class for the main window. 

    if (!hPrevInstance)
    {
        wc.style = 0;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon((HINSTANCE)NULL,
            IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor((HINSTANCE)NULL,
            IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        wc.lpszMenuName = "MainMenu";
        wc.lpszClassName = "MainWndClass";

        if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
            return FALSE;
    }

    hinst = hInstance;  

    hwndMain = CreateWindow("MainWndClass", "Sample",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 500, 30, 700, 700, (HWND)NULL,
        (HMENU)NULL, hinst, (LPVOID)NULL);

    hwndList = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, "", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT |
        LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER | LVS_SORTDESCENDING, 5, 5, 470, 630, hwndMain, (HMENU)44444, 0, 0);

    HWND btn = CreateWindow("Button", "Select element 2", WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_VISIBLE, 500, 5, 150, 30, hwndMain, (HMENU)44445, 0, 0);

    HWND btn2 = CreateWindow("Button", "Sorting", WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_VISIBLE, 500, 55, 150, 30, hwndMain, (HMENU)44446, 0, 0);

    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx(hwndList, 0, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_FLATSB);

    CreateColumn(hwndList, 1, 0, 450);

    fillListView();


    if (!hwndMain)
        return FALSE;

    ShowWindow(hwndMain, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwndMain);

    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case 44445:
        {
            LVFINDINFO lvfiInfo;
            lvfiInfo.flags = LVFI_STRING;
            lvfiInfo.psz = "2";
            int iIndex = ListView_FindItem(hwndList, -1, &lvfiInfo);
            if (iIndex != -1)
            {
                ListView_SetItemState(hwndList, iIndex, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
                SetFocus(hwndList);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox(hWnd, "Not found", "ERROR", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }

            break;
        }
        case 44446:
        {
            ListView_SortItemsEx(hwndList, CompareListViewFunc, 0);

            break;
        }
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Surely, we don't need to see your About dialog procedure. Even more so since we cannot see the dialog resource it is constructed from. Taking the [tour] is recommended.

Comment: this is a project template in the visual studio classic Windows application, you will need to replace only one include... If this is not an achievable task, then I will correct the question now

Comment: the question has been edited in accordance with the request above

Comment: There's a latent bug in `CompareListViewFunc()`: `strcmp()` can return positive values other than `1` so comparing against `1` for equality is wrong. You can save yourself the trouble of getting this right and just return the result from `strcmp()` unconditionally.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks for the advice, but this does not solve the problem that is in question

Comment: @jrfdsa NO?But it can select element and sort.https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEOmW.png

Comment: Does sorting even matter here? Doesn't LVM_FINDITEM just do a linear search?

Comment: @Torrecto - MSFT after sorting, when the items are in ascending order, nothing is selected

Comment: @Luke this is an example, there is a lot tied up in this search in the project, and the fact that it does not work after sorting brings problems

Comment: You're specifying `LVS_SORTDESCENDING` then doing your own sorting. Don't do that. Only do one or the other.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#arranging-sorting-and-finding-items "You can ensure that a list-view control is always sorted by specifying the LVS_SORTASCENDING or LVS_SORTDESCENDING window style. Controls with these styles use the label text of the items to sort them in ascending or descending order. You cannot supply a comparison function when using these window styles."

Comment: @Luke yes, thank you, it looks like this is the solution to the problem, you can arrange it as an answer, I'll mark it as the best

Comment: @IInspectable The broken comparison function is in fact the reason that "find" stops working. FindItem on a `LVS_SORTDESCENDING` listview uses inverted binary search. Due to the broken comparison function, the items are no longer sorted descending, and the inverted binary search fails.

Comment: @jrfdsa That's wired. You've already used `LVS_SORTDESCENDING` in window "hwndList ". So i don't think this is the cause. You want the elements was always selected even if pushing the button "sorting" like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS88v.png ,Right?

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Thank you, the issue has already been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179634/luke) said: You can ensure that a list-view control is always sorted by specifying the `LVS_SORTASCENDING` or `LVS_SORTDESCENDING` window style. Controls with these styles use the label text of the items to sort them in ascending or descending order. You cannot supply a comparison function when using these window styles.

Also, you have to know that items will only show as selected if the list-view control has focus or the `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` style is used in window style.
[image]